# Fetch all emails across all Gmail contact groups

Tags: javascript, google-contacts-api

I am trying to fetch all the emails from the user contacts using JS library.

**Setup**

1.) Initialised the `gapi client` using

```
gapi.client.init({
      apiKey: config['google']['apiKey'],
      discoveryDocs:
     ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/people/v1/rest"],
      clientId: config['google']['appId'],
      scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly"
})
```

2.) After the user grants permission, I try to fetch the contact details

```
gapi.client.people.people.connections.list({
         'resourceName': 'people/me',
         'pageSize': 500,
         'personFields': 'names,emailAddresses'
       }).then((response) => {
         let connections = response.result.connections;
         console.warn(connections);
})
```

3.) From step 2, I get **zero connections**.

However, when I perform

```
gapi.client.people.contactGroups.list()
```

I get following response

```
{
  "contactGroups": [
    {
      "resourceName": "contactGroups/all",
      "groupType": "SYSTEM_CONTACT_GROUP",
      "name": "all",
      "formattedName": "All Contacts",
      "memberCount": 13
    },
    ...
  ],
  "totalItems": 9,
  "nextSyncToken": "EJjRiq3lnNYC"
}
```

From the response, I can see that in `contactGroups/all` group, I have 13 contacts and in my account *i* can see the same number of contacts.

So, what is the proper way to get all the contacts across all the contact groups using JS library?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried using [`gapi.client.people.people.connections.list`](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list) and successfully got `200` response. I also don't get equal values.

Using `gapi.client.people.people.connections.list`, here is the response:

```
....  
],  
 "nextSyncToken": "^***",  
  "totalPeople": 19,  
  "totalItems": 19  
}
```

While in `gapi.client.people.contactGroups.list()`,

```
{
  "resourceName": "contactGroups/all",
  "groupType": "SYSTEM_CONTACT_GROUP",
  "name": "all",
  "formattedName": "All Contacts",
  "memberCount": 155
},
```

Be noted that [`people.connections.list`](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list) only provides a list of the authenticated user's contacts merged with any connected profiles. While [`contactGroups.list`](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups/list) lists all contact groups owned by the authenticated user. **Members of the contact groups are not populated.**

Comment: i was checking the `Import contacts` feature of airbnb and when i allow permission they fetch all my emails from contacts but with the JS library I get none. I wonder how do they do it